# Call super.onStart() in onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Firstly, We are know that it doesn't make sense when we call `super.onStart()` in function `onResume()` callback. But for understanding about android activity life cycle. Can any one explain for me about it.
Let me introduction more about it. I create simple activity and try to run two code version also. In version 1, I override method `onResume()` and do nothing in this function.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
}
```

And ofcourse, this code makes crash on Android when I try to run it.
However, when I run the second version, with a little change.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume");
}
```

But now, the app can run correct and display my simple activity. App still can run when I replace `super.onStart()` with `super.onCreate(null)`, `super.onRestart()`, `super.onStop()`, `super.onDestroy()`.

This is my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static String TAG = "LifeCycle " + MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStart");
    }
}
```

So, can anyone explain for me why this thing happen? Why the app still work when I do it?

Comment: Provide your complete Activity Code

Comment: It is so simple activity. I will update my question.

Comment: I can't believe its solved becase of calling onStart() from onResume(). It must be something else paste your simple activity

Comment: I posted it. I also thought like you. I think that it would make crash. But after I tried, the result make me supprise. You can do it yourself with create simple activity like me and run the code.

Comment: Look thru the AOSP codebase and find which C/C++ method gets called. Chances are it's the same one.

Comment: @Shark: You mean if we look at the AOSP, we will find that `super.onResume()` and `super.onStart()` will call the same C/C++ function?

Comment: I said to "look through the codebase and find out which C/C++ functions do `super.onResume()` and `super.onStart()` call; if it's the same one - that would explain it". I don't know which ones they call however, thats why I suggested looking and finding out.

Answer (score 1):

when  you create a Activity you extend it's **parent class Activity**. You can see the Parent Activity class by long press on your Mouse Scroller Button. There if you can see, you are actually sending the View from your subclass to the 
Parent class , which will start your activity , yea i Know android will be calling the onStart method of your parent class not your sublcass. Thats a clear cut View for us. if you want to know how a activity lifecycle works it is simple. First when you start your app onCreate method is called and then onStart is called n then When your app is on foreground OnResume is called and then once your app is in background onPause is called , if you press back button onDestroy will be called. If you want to know about the complete lifecylce's you can check it out at devlopers.android.com . Thankyou. I hope this was helpfull

Comment: Yes, I understand about override method. It is simple concept in OOP. And I also finished read the Android Activity lifecycle in devlopers.android.com. But in my case, I don't find any help from their document. If you find any thing for explain about my case, can you give me more detail?

Comment: you can never call onResume methods or onStart methods etc because these are the methods which will be called by the android by looking at your application state.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, its just method call of super. if you call onStart() from onResume(), technically it is correct but it is random call and Activity life cycle gets violated.

Comment: Can you explain more. In the version 1, I don't call `super.onResume()` and it make crash. But in version 2, I also don't call `super.onResume()` and I change with `super.onStart()`, and it work, so why?

Comment: Yes it suppose to make crash, if the first line of overridden protected method is not a call to super.methodName. If you keep super.onResume() first line that indicates you are calling the same method of super from where you are derived. It is mandatory !

Comment: But, the second version doesn't make crash. Why it doesn't make crash?

Comment: Because, it is basic inheritance principle. If you want to call any of the method from your super class. you can do so by super.methodName. Here onStart() method of base Activity is getting called from your onResume() method.

Comment: The reason the app crashes when you don't call the super methods is because the module that is calling your activity lifecycle methods is keeping track of that. The base method sets a flag when called, and the activity manager checks it after calling your MainActivity.onResume. So if you didn't call super.onResume then that flag is not set, and that's how the manager can tell you did not call the super method. Why it doesn't crash when you call mismatched supermethods? My guess is that the same variable is used for all the methods' flag and you're intentionally shooting your own foot